# Automatically submit a form with hidden fields and images when an image is selected in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, image, forms

My plan is creating a form with hidden fields and displayed images. I want to submit this form and send all "hidden" data with selected image automatically when the image is selected / clicked. The form should be without a submit button. The project is written in rails. How can I implement it?

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Why cannot your bind event like `click` on image and then call [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) on you form?

Comment: please share you current code and at what point are you facing the issues

Answer (score 0):

This ought to be the ticket:

```
image_submit_tag("image.png")
```

Any hidden tags will automatically be sent with the rest of the form, you don't need to do anything special there.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. It absolutely fits to my requirement.